# Stopwatch To Write Results To A TextFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

Using a `stopwatch()` in an ASP.NET `.aspx.cs` page. I am trying to measure performance and am not sure how to do such with a web form. I'd like to have the `start()` event fire when the procedure opens and the `stop()` event fire once the last line of code is performed in the procedure. Then write procedure name, start time and stop time to a text file. How should I go about it in C#/ASP.net?

Comment: when you say procedure you are talking about stored procedures in a database or just a method or function in your code?

Comment: The code behind pages, the actual CS pages.

Comment: You could do this in the `Global.asax` file. In the `Application_BeginRequest` method start your `StopWatch`, then in the `Application_EndRequest` stop it. This would allow it to work for **all** pages, and you would not need to add any specific code to any pages for it to work. It also measures the **entire** request, not just the page.

Comment: @EBrown - would it show the time it takes for each procedure on the code behind page to run?  I just have 1 troublesome page, that I want to find the "slow" culprit behind.

Comment: No, it would only show the **entire** request. If you only need to measure **one** page, then you should make that specific to the page. You can either, upon measurement success: store the information in a SQL database; write the information to a flat-file.

Comment: @EBrown - do I use the call to a stopwatch just like I would with a winform?

Comment: Yessir. At the beginning of the `method` just instance and start it, and at the end of the `method` write it to `[insert storage medium here]`.

Comment: @BigPimpin Since you didn't provide any code we really have no idea what "procedures" you are talking about but if you are wanting to know how long something takes you start the stopwatch before the method or function call and the stop it afterwards...it will tell you how long the function took

Comment: @Ebrown & waltmagic -- I wasn't sure if you could use stopwatch() class with a webform.  So starting/stopping my stopwatch will get the job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a decorator?  Not sure what "procedure" is but I'll give this a go...

```
public interface IProcedure
{
    void Run();
}

public class RealProcedure : IProcedure
{
    public void Run()
    {
        // Do interesting stuff
    }
}

public class LoggingProcedure : IProcedure
{
    private readonly IProcedure _procedure;

    public LoggingProcedure(IProcedure procedure)
    {
        if (procedure == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("procedure");
        _procedure = procedure;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        _procedure.Run();
        stopWatch.Stop();

        // Log elapsed time with w/e you are using for logging.
    }
}
```

If you are using a DI container you can wire up the IProcedure implementation in your composition root or you can use what Mark Seemann refers to (or used to) as poor man's DI:

```
IProcedure procedure = new LoggingProcedure(new RealProcedure());
procedure.Run();
```

Now you have the stopwatch factored in and you are right with [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).